# How can I replace an alert box with a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

How can I change the alert box into a jquery dialog box?

Part of the script coding:

```
  if(answeredAnsData.length==8){
            for(var x=0;x<8;x++){
                $('#text'+(x)).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
         window.alert("test"); //alert box here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the *[confirm](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/window.htm#confirm)* command

```
window.confirm("are you sure");
```

if you want to use the dialog box from jquery you should look into the ui extension. Example taken from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.

Comment: added the example from jquery ui for dialog boxes and added jquery reference to your question

Comment: no >< ..  i still have no idea how to apply .. because my javascript and html code is different part... should i upload full code?

Comment: put it to a pastebin and I can have a look, actually it should be not that hard with the sample code above

Comment: Hi Matt.. try have a look, i had paste my codes in here.. http://pastebin.com/BrZ3Eree  might looks messy

Comment: I am not seeing `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>` inside your code. did you miss to include that one?

Comment: oh my mistake .. i missing this javascript .. i will re-try again .. thanks for correct my mistake

Comment: Hi matt.. it is working ... but im facing another problem ..that is when i view my screen into mobile size.. the dialog does not fit stretch to the screen size.. any other ways to let the dialog fit to any platform ?

Comment: sure you can use `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height", 400 );` as you can see in the API documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/ You just need to calculate, what height suits the current display, calculate and use the setter

Answer (score 1):

We can use confirm

result = confirm("To confirm  click OK");

To see all options http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

To use jquery dialog

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can be change to jquery dialog box ? instead of the window box .

Comment: yaya, you're right.. but i have no idea.. how to apply ..
i try with this code.. it is still not working, 
result ='<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">test.</div>';

Comment: Download the jQuery-ui css and js files. Include them in your HTMl file. I will update my answer

Comment: Yeap, i had included those in my files. Thank for help raji .